# Do objects declared within loops get constructed only once?

Tags: c++, loops, lifetime

Suppose we have a method. Inside the method is a loop with n iterations, where an object `myObj` is declared and initialized.

- How many times is it constructed and destroyed? Once, or n times?
- When does construction happen - when the line is executed, or when
  the program calls the method?
- When does the destruction happen? At the end of each iteration, at
  the end of the for block, or the end of the method?

Example:

```
void foo()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   {
       A myObj();
   }
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, the code constructs and destroys A object [*zero* times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How many times is it constructed and destroyed? Once, or n times?

n times.

> When does construction happen - when the line is executed, or when the program calls the method?

When the line is executed.

> When does the destruction happen? At the end of each iteration, at the end of the for block, or the end of the method?

When get out of the object's scope; for your sample code, at the end of each iteration.

---

BTW: `A myObj();` is not an object's definition, but a function's declaration. You might mean `A myObj;` or `A myObj{};` (since C++11). Search [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

In your code `myObj` is *declared* but never *defined*. `myObj` is declared as a function taking no arguments and returning an object of type `A`.

A declaration that is not a definition has no runtime effect so there is no construction on each iteration of the loop.

Had you declared and defined an object inside the loop body then it would be constructed at the point of definition and destructed at the end of its scope (the end of the loop body) on each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

100 different objects are constructed and destroyed.

Having said that, if the construction and destruction of the object is trivial, you will not see a performance cost.

Further, if an optimising compiler is able to determine that the constructions and destructions have no observable effect on the outcome, it is free to remove redundant code.

However, as a rule of thumb, it is good practice to construct objects in loops only if you require the construction and destruction behaviours.